# Youtube live streaming API

Tags: api, youtube

I'm working on a web application that would allow streaming a webcam (connected to a pc) to a desktop or mobile phone (including iOS and Android). I've been researching different approaches to this, until I came across Youtube's live streaming API.

If I understand correctly, this API would allow us to upload a webcam feed and stream it live through youtube servers. Is this correct? I didn't see any mention of a fee for this service. Wouldn't it be costly to allow users to constantly stream videos live?

Does anyone know if this API is now available for all developers (without the 1000 subscription limit)? 
Can this be used commercially? 
In what format should the webcam feed be uploaded to youtube?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Ravi

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about clarifying Youtube's policies and doing customer support work for Google.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I'm really trying to find out if this API can be used for a commercial application. I've tried to pose this question on the google developers site, but, the 'Get Help' section there redirects to this website.

Comment: I disagree Renan's comment that this question is off-topic. It is the right kind of question I would like to follow on SO.

SO's off-topic-marking procedure needs to improve -- it feels like a lot of unprofessional marking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API allows your application to connect to a live enabled YouTube channel and perform certain functions of the live event UI.
Any YouTube channel with 100 subscribers (not 1000) can apply for the live events feature.
All streams should adhere to the recommended encoding specifications. 
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853702?hl=en&ref_topic=2853713